# Maven including non-defined dependencies

Tags: java, maven

My Maven is failing with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sdcf4j-twitch: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.github.twitch4j:sdcf4j-twitch:jar:1.0.9: Failed to collect dependencies at com.github.twitch4j:twitch4j:jar:v0.10.2 -> org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:+: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:+: Could not transfer artifact org.projectlombok:lombok:pom:+ from/to jitpack.io (https://jitpack.io): Transfer failed for https://jitpack.io/org/projectlombok/lombok/+/lombok-+.pom 400 Bad Request -> [Help 1]
```

I already tried completely wiping Intellij IDEA's files, and re-adding the dependencies, which didn't help with the error, but some wrong dependencies, that my IDE displayed.
Of course I already tried without any lombok plugin, (lombok) annotation paths and a `mvn clear`, but that didn't help either.

The Maven code for that project is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>de.btobastian.sdcf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdcf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.github.twitch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdcf4j-twitch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.16</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Include source -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Include JavaDocs -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <stylesheet>java</stylesheet>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- The core module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.btobastian.sdcf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdcf4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.twitch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitch4j</artifactId>
            <version>v0.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The Parent Pom does not differ from the original at https://github.com/Bastian/sdcf4j/blob/8f569ee5dc36be09c6595c12833d109b7127c23e/pom.xml.

If one sets up the folders correctly, you can add `sdcf4j-twitch` as a module in `sdcf4j`, just like `sdcf4j-core`,`sdcf4j-discord4j` in [L17](https://github.com/Bastian/sdcf4j/blob/8f569ee5dc36be09c6595c12833d109b7127c23e/pom.xml#L17)

Complete Build log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< com.github.twitch4j:sdcf4j-twitch >------------------
[INFO] Building sdcf4j-twitch 1.0.9
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from jitpack.io: https://jitpack.io/org/projectlombok/lombok/+/lombok-+.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.968 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-10T22:55:31+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sdcf4j-twitch: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.github.twitch4j:sdcf4j-twitch:jar:1.0.9: Failed to collect dependencies at com.github.twitch4j:twitch4j:jar:v0.10.2 -> org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:+: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:+: Could not transfer artifact org.projectlombok:lombok:pom:+ from/to jitpack.io (https://jitpack.io): Transfer failed for https://jitpack.io/org/projectlombok/lombok/+/lombok-+.pom 400 Bad Request -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: It doesn't help that these twitch4j people don't seem to have bothered to publish to Central.

Comment: Based on just the error, it looks like twitch4j might have two problems in its POM: It hasn't scoped Lombok correctly (it shouldn't be transitive) _and_ it hasn't defined a version for it. Hard to say for certain without its POM, though; if you can post a link that would be helpful. You might try excluding Lombok from your dependency.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I am currently working (forking) on(/with) [not yet!] sdcf4-twitch. How do I not make lombok a transitive, and what is that? also, why doesn't it have a version? I am defining one. I even followed lomboks installation instructions. Even if I exclude Lombok from all pom , it still failes with that exact error.